# Apache redirecting to removed virtual host

Tags: apache

I have a strange issue with my Apache. I added a new virtual host and I noticed if I browse to it it redirects to another hosts home directory. I have host1, host2 and newly created host3. If I browse to address for host 3 it would take me to host1 site. 
I removed host1 now but it still trying to take me to host1 (Apache log has"
[Thu Jul 24 16:31:33 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/WWW/htdocs/public/host1/index.html  "  which is home directory for host1 site which is removed from httpd.conf. Apache service restarted, all other .conf files checked - no mentioning of host1.
here how its configured:

```
################# host2 ############################
<VirtualHost host2.net:80>


DocumentRoot "C:/WWW/htdocs/host2/public/"
ServerName host2
ServerAlias host2.local

<Directory "C:/WWW/htdocs/host2/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>



################# host3 ############################
<VirtualHost host3.net:80>


DocumentRoot "C:/WWW/htdocs/host3/public/"
ServerName host3
ServerAlias host3.local

<Directory "C:/WWW/htdocs/host3/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just in case, I suggest you remove your browser's cache.

Comment: did it. Tried different browsers, even rebooted apache server and PC.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody have the same issue - I just found one software on my PC that has been messing with port 80. Once that software removed - my apache works fine